# How do I post to a Facebook timeline?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have an app which uses the Facebook PHP SDK.  It used to be a simple matter to post to a user's Facebook wall.  I would do the authentication, and then something like:

```
    $ret_obj = $Facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                            array(
                              'link' => 'www.example.com',
                              'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'
                         ));
```

and on their wall the link would appear.  Since Timeline was introduced, however, this doesn't seem to work.  I don't get an error, I just don't get anything back.  I can't find any helpful documentation on how this should work.

### More info

I don't get any error, I just get "NULL" returned in $ret_obj.

If I do something like

```
$ret_obj = $Facebook->api('/me', 'GET');
```

then it works fine - I get the user's information back.  So it's connecting ok, just not posting.

Comment: var_dump($ret_obj) what produce?

Comment: What error do you get? All examples with the SDK, the docs and the examples on fbrell.com should work

Comment: I just get 'NULL' when I do var_dump($ret_obj)

Comment: Could you provide a complete presentation of the bare bones of your code, there maybe something else that is causing it

Answer (score 2):

Double check that you have allowed `publish_stream` permission.

You can refer to [PHP SDK and JavaScript SDK Feed Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649256/suggest-page-to-friends-using-php-sdk/10869074#10869074) for more examples.

Official Documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/