# Allow user to select friend(s) from a dialog that lists all of the user's friends, and post on their wall using Javascript Facebook SDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, friend

I would like to have a button in my Facebook app that will bring up a dialog that will allow the user to pick a friend's wall to post on.  I was pretty sure this kind of dialog exists but so fare I have only been able to find a dialog that will allow you to send messages to a friend or post to a specific Facebook user's wall (without a dialog) but I cannot find anywhere in the documentation where it describes how to bring up a dialog that allows selection of user's to publish to.  Is this possible?  If so could someone post a link to some documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the thesedays Facebook-friend-selector which works very nicely.

It has a Facebook style look and feel and filled my needs:

[image]

https://github.com/thesedays/Facebook-friend-selector

Answer (score 1):

You can use Facebook's **Multi-Friend-Selector(MFS)**.

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/games/custom-muti-friend-selector/

Comment: Ok I got the selection to work, but how do you actually post to someone else's wall?

Comment: Now that you have a list of checkboxes, you can use JavaScript to check which checkboxes are checked and get a list of Facebook IDs through the `value` property. To post to wall of each selected user, you will need to use Feed Dialog's `to` property. You can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649256/suggest-page-to-friends-using-php-sdk/10869074#10869074 for examples using both PHP & JavaScript SDK.

Comment: Note: The reference posted just above does not use the `to` property but you can read more on Feed Dialog over here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/